# splitting into new columns as many time separator between column values has occurred

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I’ve a Dataframe where in some columns there are multiple values, always separated by ^

```
phone|contact|
ERN~58XXXXXX7~^EPN~5XXXXX551~|C~MXXX~MSO~^CAxxE~~~~~~3XXX5|

phone1|phone2|contact1|contact2| 
ERN~5XXXXXXX7|EPN~58XXXX91551~|C~MXXXH~MSO~|CAxxE~~~~~~3XXX5|
```

How can this be achieved using loop as the separator between column values
 are not constant.

Comment: Have you tried something at least ?

Comment: data.withColumn("phone",split($"phone","\\^")).select($"phone".getItem(0).as("phone1"),$"phone".getItem(1).as("phone2")) I have though of doing this way  but the problem is one of the column have 100+  separator between the column  values.

Comment: You are getting an error ?

Comment: No, I am not getting an error but I want to achieve this in the loop so that I don't have to mention new columns in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("charset", "UTF-8").load("test.txt").
          val columnList=df.columns


          val xx = columnList.map(x => x->0).toMap
          val opMap = df.rdd.flatMap { row =>
            columnList.foldLeft(xx) { case (y, col) =>
              val s = row.getAs[String](col).split("\\^").length

              if (y(col) < s)
                y.updated(col, s)
              else
                y
            }.toList
          }
      val colMaxSizeMap = opMap.groupBy(x => x._1).map(x => x._2.toList.maxBy(x => x._2)).collect().toMap
          val x = df.rdd.map{x =>
            val op = columnList.flatMap{ y =>
              val op = x.getAs[String](y).split("\\^")
              op++List.fill(colMaxSizeMap(y)-op.size)("")
            }
            Row.fromSeq(op)
          }

          val structFieldList = columnList.flatMap{colName =>
            List.range(0,colMaxSizeMap(colName),1).map{ i =>
              StructField(s"$colName"+s"$i",StringType)
            }
          }
          val schema = StructType(structFieldList)

          val da= spark.createDataFrame(x,schema)
```